# How to initialize an array which is already been declared inside the class, without using constructor or member function

Tags: c++, arrays, constructor, getter-setter

I would like to initialize a normal array in C++.

```
class Test {

    public: int a[5];
    a[0] = {1}; // or simply a[0] = 1;
    
};

int main(){

    Test Obj;
    cout<<Obj.a[0];
}
```

It gives an error "a does not name a type".
There is another method which I'm aware of: initializing using constructor or using member function.
My entire point of asking is, why should I use any getter and setter methods just to initialize the normal array? Does it break any C++ rule and why am I getting this error?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33991363/is-it-possible-to-initialize-an-array-in-a-member-initializer-list-in-c does this answer it?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Why not just do `int a[5]{1};`?

Comment: cigien, i was trying to initialize the array in that way we do the in c or out of the class in ++

Comment: That would be assignment, not initialization. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23850656/assigning-one-array-to-another-array-c

Answer (score 1):

You can initialize the array like this in the same line

```
class Test{

public: 
int a[5] = {1};
};
```

it will set the first value with 1.

Comment: sorry to say but it will set all value of entire array is 1 which means a[0]= 1 and a[1] = 1 and so on.. until the a[5], that is not what i'm trying to do here, i want to set all the index values individually, i mean one by one .

Comment: I actually tried it and it didn't, it set only the first one with 1

Comment: my question got marked as duplicate, i searched on the internet how to do this simple thing, but badly there is no answer.

Comment: @HãŕşhįțŚïñğh I don't follow. This solution seems to do exactly what you want. What is the issue with it?

Comment: @HãŕşhįțŚïñğh you can do that like this: int a[5] = {1,2,3,4,5}; does this answer your question?

Comment: actually my main focus was to know why i was getting that error, when i was trying to initializing in that way ? just because whats c++ has been thinking is , when it was trying to compile the line a[0] = 2; is, c++ should have  to declare the array with the name a and assign the value of 2 in the 0th index, but as we can see there is no data type, that is why its throwing an error beacuse of missing the data type. and what i was trying to do is first declare the array with the appropriate size and than assign the array values with their index later on. hope you guys have a idea of mine now.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a constructor:

```
class Test{

public: int a[5];

  Test() {a[0]=1; a[1]=5; a[2]=4; a[3]=8; a[4] = 9;}
    }
};
```

Comment: "*must*" is a bit strong, as that requirement hasn't been needed since C++11 added the ability to initialize class members directly in their declarations.

Comment: why should i use the constructor here ? does c++ not allow that kind of initialization which  I'm doing in my code ?