# Is an array in a member initializer list for a variadic struct possible?

Tags: c++, struct, stdtuple, type-deduction, ctor-initializer

I created a variadic struct based on a `std::tuple`.

Then, I would like to use a C-style array in the member initializer list with automatic type deduction / class template argument deduction.

I created a minimum reproducible example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>

template <typename ... Args>
struct VariadicStruct {
    std::tuple<Args...> data{};
    VariadicStruct() {}
    VariadicStruct(Args...args) {
        data = std::make_tuple(args...);
    };
    // More data and functions
    // . . .
};
int main() {
    VariadicStruct vs1{ {1,2,3}, 4.0, 'c' }; // Does not work
    std::cout << std::get<0>(vs1.data)[0] << '\t' << std::get<1>(vs1.data) << '\t' << std::get<2>(vs1.data) << '\n';

    VariadicStruct vs2{ 1, 4.0, 'c' };   // Fine
    std::cout << std::get<0>(vs2.data) << '\t' << std::get<1>(vs2.data) << '\t' << std::get<2>(vs2.data) << '\n';
}
```

I was hoping to create an array in the `std::tuple` using a nested braced initializer list. So, in the end, a `std::tuple` with `int[3]`, `double`and `char` types.

My guess: Automatic type deduction does not work here.

Is there any way to make this happen?

---

(This is not a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33991363/is-it-possible-to-initialize-an-array-in-a-member-initializer-list-in-c))

Comment: `{1,2,3}` has no type

Comment: I guess that this is the answer, why it does not compile. Just to confirm: is this not a `std::initializer_list<int>`? Maybe not. But is there any other solution possible to achieve, what I want?

Comment: `{1,2,3}` does not participate in type deduction.

Comment: you can use `std::array<int,3>{1,2,3}`

Comment: btw no need for `make_tuple`, use the initializer list `VariadicStruct(Args...args) : data(args...) {};` and you probably want perfect forwarding, rather than pass by value (which wouldnt work with a c-array anyhow)

Comment: note that there is a special rule for `auto` that makes `auto a = {1,2,3};` work and deduces `std::initializer_list<int>`, but thats also explained in the dupe

Comment: Spell it as `std::array{1,2,3}`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: `std::array{1,2,3}` looks like the best solution for my needs. Thank you very much (to all of you).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the very good comments from the community, I now implemented the code like the below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <array>
#include <utility>

template <typename ... Args>
struct VariadicStruct {

    std::tuple<Args...> data{};

    VariadicStruct() {}
    VariadicStruct(Args...args) : data(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...)  {};

    // More data and functions
    // . . .
};
int main() {
    VariadicStruct vs1{ std::array{1,2,3}, 4.0, 'c' };
    std::cout << std::get<0>(vs1.data)[0] << '\t' << std::get<1>(vs1.data) << '\t' << std::get<2>(vs1.data) << '\n';
}
```